# Python exponent operator and multiplication

Tags: python, math, operation

I'm trying to get an exponential-multiply operation work but the output is not what i expected. It should be a simple operation where the programs takes in a number, and multiply by the 10³.

input: 9
expected output: 9000

actual output:
    9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

This is my code:

```py
num = input("Please enter a number:")
n1 = 10**3
output = n1*num
print(output)
```

Comment: The problem is the type of your input.  You have to cast it to an integer (or real) otherwise it is considered a string (array of characters)

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code using a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply a `str` by an `int`, the string repeats:

```
>>> "foobar" * 10
'foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar'
```

You're multiplying the string `"9"` by the number `1000`, meaning you get a string of one thousand "9"s.

If you want to multiply the *number* `9` by the number `1000`, that would look more like:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
n1 = 10**3
print(n1*num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
output = (10 ** 3) * num
print(output)
```